# How does one connect to a GTK signal with a dash inside it while using Quickly?

Tags: quickly, pygtk

I'm currently writing an app with Quickly where I want to connect to the "preedit-changed" signal of an entry box. While with signals like clicked where you can write a function on_button1_clicked, you can't just do that with preedit-changed because of the dash. Will I have to connect the signal manually, or is there an alternate character to replace the dash with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply do something like the following to connect to any signal. From working code:

```
self.event_connect_signal(classchan, 'message-received', self._message_received)
```